# python asyncio how to read StdIn and write to StdOut?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, stdout, stdin

I have a need to async read StdIn in order to get messages (json terminated by \r\n) and after processing async write updated message to StdOut.

At the moment I am doing it synchronous like:

```
class SyncIOStdInOut():
    def write(self, payload: str):
        sys.stdout.write(payload)
        sys.stdout.write('\r\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def read(self) -> str:
        payload=sys.stdin.readline()
        return  payload
```

How to do the same but asynchronously?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's an example of echo `stdin` to `stdout` using [asyncio streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html) (for Unix).

```
import asyncio
import sys


async def connect_stdin_stdout():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    reader = asyncio.StreamReader()
    protocol = asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol(reader)
    await loop.connect_read_pipe(lambda: protocol, sys.stdin)
    w_transport, w_protocol = await loop.connect_write_pipe(asyncio.streams.FlowControlMixin, sys.stdout)
    writer = asyncio.StreamWriter(w_transport, w_protocol, reader, loop)
    return reader, writer


async def main():
    reader, writer = await connect_stdin_stdout()
    while True:
        res = await reader.read(100)
        if not res:
            break
        writer.write(res)
        await writer.drain()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

---

As a ready-to-use solution, you could use [aioconsole](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aioconsole) library. It implements a similar approach, but also provide additional useful asynchronous equivalents to `input`, `print`, `exec` and `code.interact`:

```
from aioconsole import get_standard_streams

async def main():
    reader, writer = await get_standard_streams()
```

#### Update:

Let's try to figure out how the function `connect_stdin_stdout` works.

1. Get the current event loop:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

2. Create `StreamReader` instance.

```
reader = asyncio.StreamReader()
```

Usually, `StreamReader/StreamWriter` classes are not intended to be directly instantiated and should only be used as a result of functions such as `open_connection()` and `start_server()`.
`StreamReader` provides a buffered asynchronous interface to some data stream. Some source(library code) calls its functions such as `feed_data`, `feed_eof`, the data is buffered and can be read using the [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html?highlight=streamreader#streamreader) interface coroutine `read()`, `readline()`, and etc.

3. Create `StreamReaderProtocol` instance.

```
protocol = asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol(reader)
```

This class is derived from `asyncio.Protocol` and `FlowControlMixin` and helps to adapt between `Protocol` and `StreamReader`. It overrides such `Protocol` methods as `data_received`, `eof_received` and calls `StreamReader` methods `feed_data`.

4. Register standard input stream `stdin` in the event loop.

```
await loop.connect_read_pipe(lambda: protocol, sys.stdin)
```

The `connect_read_pipe` function takes as a `pipe` parameter a file-like object. `stdin` is a file-like object. From now, all data read from the `stdin` will fall into the `StreamReaderProtocol` and then pass into `StreamReader`

5. Register standard output stream `stdout` in the event loop.

```
w_transport, w_protocol = await loop.connect_write_pipe(FlowControlMixin, sys.stdout)
```

In `connect_write_pipe` you need to pass a protocol factory that creates protocol instances that implement flow control logic for `StreamWriter.drain()`. This logic is implemented in the class `FlowControlMixin`. Also `StreamReaderProtocol` inherited from it.

6. Create `StreamWriter` instance.

```
writer = asyncio.StreamWriter(w_transport, w_protocol, reader, loop)
```

This class forwards the data passed to it using functions `write()`, `writelines()` and etc. to the underlying `transport`.

`protocol` is used to support the `drain()` function to wait for the moment that the underlying transport has flushed its internal buffer and is available for writing again.

`reader` is an optional parameter and can be `None`, it is also used to support the `drain()` function, at the start of this function it is checked if an exception was set for the reader, for example, due to a connection lost (relevant for sockets and bidirectional connections), then `drain()` will also throw an exception.

You can read more about `StreamWriter` and `drain()` function in this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53781454/13782669).

#### Update 2:

To read lines with `\r\n` separator [readuntil](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader.readuntil) can be used

Comment: Can you please explain a bit concept here. For example, what is the purpose of the reader, protocol, connect_read_pipe, w_transport, connect_write_pipe? What is the purpose of all those elements and how they work with conenct_read/write_pipe? Why you needed dummy as a protocol? How come writer uses the same protocol as reader? I believe that for reading lines I should use reader.readline(). How to set line termination to \r\n for reading and writing? As you can see I am quite confused, but your solution works. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Also, I have just noticed that writer is not awaited.

Comment: Hello, I will try to describe in more detail a little later

Comment: Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the furthest I have come: https://pastebin.com/2Rwch6Dr

Comment: can you please answer?

Comment: I changed the function a bit and updated the answer

Comment: Alex, at first thank you very much for your very detailed answer. I have carefully read every word of it. Still I have some issues. :) I saw that connect_read_pipe returns (transport, protocol), but from your code I can see that you are not interested to those values. As protocol is defined a line above, I am concluding that we don't need read transport at all. If I understood you correctly, connect_read_pipe will enable me to use await reader.read(100) whenever I need to read data from StdIn. Regarding writes (it will continue in next comment)...

Comment: Why StreamWriter neds reader as a third parameter? If I would like to write to StdErr, will this be enough?     e_transport, e_protocol = await loop.connect_write_pipe(asyncio.streams.FlowControlMixin, sys.stderr)
    e_writer = asyncio.StreamWriter(e_transport, e_protocol, reader, loop)
[do I still need reader?]. I have to use stderr for logging. After everything you have said I am not sure should I use these lines above or somthing like aiologger. Anyway, thank you very much for all information you have provided. Best regards.

Comment: You are right about `connect_read_pipe`. For the rest I have updated item 6

Comment: Alex, thank you very much for all information you have provided. Everything works as it should. Best regards.

Comment: Is it a typo in not awaiting for `writer.write` call?

Comment: No, [it's not](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamWriter.write) a typo. But it is correct to use `write` in conjunction with `await drain()`. I've updated the answer. Thank you for your notice.

Answer (score 2):

This is another way you can async read from stdin (reads a single line at a time).

```
async def async_read_stdin()->str:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, sys.stdin.readline)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer what @alex_noname has suggested.

Comment: If the asycnio task that calls this is cancelled, then the background thread blocking on readline() will still be running and due to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49992422/1976323 the program will not exit.

Comment: this is doing blocking call with thread pool? I think this is not TRUE async.