# Should Python process wait for a job forked using `run_in_executor`, although I did not wait for?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, python-3.9

Assume we have the following script:

```py
def sync_sleep(x):
    print("sync_sleep going to sleep")
    time.sleep(x)
    print("sync_sleep awake")


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_sleep, 4)
    print("main going to sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("main awake ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    print("main finished")
```

**Note**: I have omitted `loop.close` intentionally.

Now when I execute the above script:

```sh
python script.py
```

I have the following output:

```
sync_sleep going to sleep
main going to sleep
main awake 
main finished
sync_sleep awake
```

I expected after running the script, the process to exit after printing `"main finished"`, but it did not until the job `sync_sleep` has finished. I mean, if I wanted to wait for that job, I would  have added the line:

```py
loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_default_executor())
```

Is my expectation wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The default `ThreadPoolExecutor` [waits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49992329/1658617) at exit for daemon threads, meaning the process waits for the thread to finish, and only then stops.

Apart from implementing an [`Executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor) class yourself , there's no option other than using the `threading` module to create a new thread with `daemon=True`. If you wish to wait for that thread in `asyncio`, you can always run an executor to `await` the `thread.join()`.